# How do you solve $x^2−4\equiv 0 \mod 7$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How do you solve $x^2−4\equiv 0 \mod 7$?

Comment: hint: how to solve $ab\equiv 0\pmod 7$ ?

Comment: 1. Try $x\equiv 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 \pmod 7$. 2. Factor.

Comment: i have done it thx alot

Comment: $x^2\equiv4\iff x\equiv\pm2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient method here is that $x^2-4=(x-2)(x+2)$, thus it implies that $7$ divides $(x-2)(x+2)$ but because $7$ is a prime, it must divide either $x+2$ or $x-2$, therefore the solutions are $x=±2$ (mod $7$)

Comment: true and also will have  x=±5

Comment: Those are the same mod7

Comment: yea and that what we will need , thx alot

Comment: what if we have x^2 + 3x ≡ 4 ( mod 5 )? we can do that x^2 + 3x ≡ 4 is equal to (x+4)(x-1) ≡ 0 ( mod 5 ) ? if its right how i can continue that ?

Comment: Yeah its completely correct. Now because 5 is a prime the only possibilities are that 5 divides one of those two